# Reduce code repetition in express API route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm learning express and am currently writing an API, and have this structure:

```
app.route('/api/brief/:_id')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    // Check if the _id is a valid ObjectId
    if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params._id)) {
      // Do something
    }else{
      // Error
    }
  })
  .put(function(req, res, next) {
    // Check if the _id is a valid ObjectId
    if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params._id)) {
      // Do something
    }else{
      // Error
    }
  })
  .delete(function(req, res, next) {
    // Check if the _id is a valid ObjectId
    if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params._id)) {
      // Do something
    }else{
      // Error
    }
  });
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid the repetition (checking the validity of the ID).

Is there a way that I can structure the route as to avoid that repetition?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can approach it. There is the [`app.all()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.all) method:

```
app.all("/api/*", function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.params._id) {

        if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params._id)) {
            return next();
        }
        else {
            // error handle
        }
    }
    next();
});
```

Personally, I don't like catch-alls. I'd rather be more explicit:

```
function validateMongooseId (req, res, next) {

    if ( mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params._id) ) {
        return next();
    }
    else {
        // error handle
    }
}

function handleGet(req, res, next) {}
function handlePost(req, res, next) {}
function handlePut(req, res, next) {}

app.post("/api/brief", handlePost);
app.get("/api/brief/:_id", validateMongooseId, handleGet);
app.put("/api/brief/:_id", validateMongooseId, handlePut);
```

I put the `.post()` in there to demonstrate why I don't like the catch-all. It clearly doesn't apply to that endpoint. You may have other middleware functions that apply to it, so I'd rather explicitly have them on the endpoints that use them.

Comment: Really useful, thanks. I was actually able to implement the first suggestion quite easily (whilst bypassing the `POST`) by using `app.all("/api/brief/:_id"…`